# Looking for name of very old board-type game

Tags: identify-this-game

[image]I do not remember if it is competitive, cooperative or solo game.

- It is played with small cubes having a different marking on each side representing directions such as straight, turn, an X, diagonal, and two other symbols I don't recall.
- The board has numerous square notches in it for the cubes to fit in. The notches are aligned in columns/rows similar to a chess board with connecting lines.
- I do not know what the goal of the game is.
- I know that the cubes can only be moved in the direction of the marking on the current face of it.
- It's possible the game may even be ancient in origin.

I found the game in a book of games that no longer exist. There were diagrams of the game along with detailed playing instructions. I made a physical copy of the game about 20 years ago, but accidentally threw it out last year.
The book I found it in was one of those history-of-board-games books, but I do not remember the title and I've not found the game in other books of those type.

[image]

Comment: Can you make a guess on the title of the book you had it from?

Comment: Why did you tag this quoridor?  Quoridor is a specific game which, as far as I can tell, this question is unrelated to.

Comment: @Gary N. it looks like you may have split into two accounts by accident, you may want to contact a Mod to have them merge back your accounts.

Comment: I've removed the Quoridor tag.

Comment: Was the book "The Way to Play" ? https://www.amazon.com/Play-Illustrated-Encyclopedia-Games-World/dp/0846700603

Answer (score -1):

Its form is that of "Tigers and Goats" or "Tiger Move" (Bagha Chal), and its cell number indicates that it is a puzzle rather than a game, or  variant.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your answer would be greatly improved if you could provide a bit more information and a source to support it.

Comment: The cube appears to be nothing to do with Bagh-Chal, as far as I can determine from [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagh-Chal).